# Scientific proof of sign language for toddler communication

Tags: toddler, teaching, research, sign-language

Is there science-backed research on teaching sign language to toddlers to enhance communication?

Comment: Do you have specific concerns about it? SE sites aren't generally just a source of "give me a paper" - we're here to actually answer specific questions. Can you expand on your question to explain what you're specifically interested in as it relates to using sign language with toddlers?

Comment: Have you had trouble finding one? What were your search terms? I googled this: "benefits of sign language, babies, journal" and the first 6 results are journal articles...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic- any prior research would get multiple answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: https://www.google.com/search?q=benefits+of+sign+language%2C+babies%2C+journal

1. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1868823/

**Quote:**

> Existing research suggests that there may be benefits to teaching
>   signing to hearing infants who have not yet developed vocal
>   communication. In the current study, each of 4 infants ranging in age
>   from 6 to 10 months was taught a simple sign using delayed prompting
>   and reinforcement. In addition, Experiment 1 showed that 2 children
>   independently signed in a variety of novel stimulus conditions (e.g.,
>   in a classroom, with father) after participating in sign training
>   under controlled experimental conditions. In Experiment 2, crying and
>   whining were replaced with signing when sign training was implemented
>   in combination with extinction.
>
> Keywords: communication training, extinction, infants, modeling,
>   physical prompting, reinforcement, sign language, delay Sign language
>   systems have been used successfully with individuals who have
>   difficulty learning to communicate through vocal language. In addition
>   to individuals with hearing impairments, individuals with
>   developmental disabilities such as autism and mental retardation have
>   learned to communicate through signs (Bryen & Joyce, 1986). Signing
>   may be a good alternative to vocal communication for individuals who
>   have poor oral motor control but adequate manual control. For these
>   individuals, sign language may be easier to teach than oral language
>   because signing can be physically prompted by a caregiver (i.e., a
>   child's hands can be molded to form a sign; Tabor, 1988).
>
> These advantages have led some researchers and clinicians to recommend
>   that signing also be taught to typically developing children during
>   their first 2 years of life (Acredolo & Goodwyn, 1996; Garcia, 1999).
>   This recommendation is supported by studies showing that infants
>   exposed to sign language acquired first signs at an earlier age than
>   typical first spoken words. Bonvillian, Orlansky, and Novack (1983)
>   studied 11 hearing children of deaf parents and reported that children
>   produced their first recognizable sign at a mean age of just
>   8.5 months, with the earliest first sign at 5.5 months. Similarly, Goodwyn and Acredolo (1993) found that, when hearing parents were
>   trained to encourage the use of symbolic gestures (e.g., palms up for
>   “Where is it?”), their hearing infants began to use gestures a mean of
>   0.69 months before their first vocal words.
>
> A concern associated with the early use of sign language is the
>   potential for a delay in the onset of vocal language; however, results
>   of a study by Goodwyn, Acredolo, and Brown (2000) suggest that sign
>   training might facilitate rather than hinder the development of vocal
>   language. In this study, hearing infants whose parents encouraged
>   symbolic gestures outperformed children whose parents encouraged vocal
>   language on follow-up tests of receptive and expressive vocal
>   language.

Comment: Hi and welcome. This is too long a quote for an answer. Quotes should highlight points in your answer. Otherwise it's just a copy and paste answer, which is discouraged on SE sites. Please edit. Thanks.